# keep rows with the same results or which should have some pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Hello i need you to sort and delete rows.

```
column 1   |  column 2   |  column 3   |result   |
    +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
  1 | 45          | artisan    | class1        |0        |
  2 | 45          | artisan    | class1        |1        |
  3 | 45          | student    | class2        |0        |
  4 | 45          | artisan    | class2        |1        |
  5 | 50          | student    | class2        |1        |
  6 | 50          | artisant   | class1        |0        |
  7 | 50          | student    | class1        |0        |
```

if the rows of the column are the same and if with the classes the results in result column are different we keep them otherwise we remove them.
I wanted to do a groupby and drop but I can't find the solution

```
  column 1   |  column 2   |  column 3   |result  |
    +-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
   1| 45          | artisan    | class1        |0        |
   2| 45          | artisan    | class1        |1        |
   4| 45          | artisan    | class2        |1        |
   5| 50          | student    | class2        |1        |
   7| 50          | student    | class1        |0        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want number of unique values per groups by first 2 columns greater like `1` use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby(['column 1','column 2'])['result'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
print (df)
   column 1 column 2 column 3  result
1        45  artisan   class1       0
2        45  artisan   class1       1
4        45  artisan   class2       1
5        50  student   class2       1
7        50  student   class1       0
```